# toString() in Kotlin - wrong output

Tags: kotlin

I have written some codes for printing out objects in array with toString()

but by using Option1 `println(path.toString())`

Output is [LRunningpath;@27973e9b

which is not what i want. Then i replace it with Option2 as follow

```
var i=0
for(i in 0 until path.size)
println(path[i].toString())
```

which is correct.

My questions are,

1. why Option 1 don't work?
2. what does the output in Option 1 mean?
3. any advice to avoid the same situation in the future?

Any hints is very appreciated. Thank you for the kindness.

my codes are as below:

```
fun main() {
    println("Warming up")
    val input1 = Runningpath("in Forest", 2000, "some houses")
    val input2 = Runningpath("at lake", 1500, "a school")
    val path = arrayOf(input1, input2 )
    println(path.toString())
/*    var i=0
    for(i in 0 until path.size)
    println(path[i].toString())
   */
}
class  Runningpath(val name: String, val length: Int, val spot: String){
    override fun toString(): String= "The Path $name ($length m) is near $spot"
}
```

Comment: If you use listOf instead of arrayOf, it will use Runningpath.toString for the two elements.

Comment: Thanks, it works! but if i use listOf, all inputs are in the same row, is it possible to make each input in seperate rows?

Comment: You can do `paths.joinToString("\n")`

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: in most cases, it's better to use lists instead of arrays.

Arrays are mostly for historical reasons, for compatibility, and for implementing low-level data structures.  In Kotlin, you sometimes need them for interoperability with Java, and for handling [vararg](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) arguments.  But other than those, lists have many advantages.

The problem is that on the JVM, an array is very different from all other objects.  It has only the methods inherited from [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), and doesn't override those.  (And you can't create your own subclasses to override or add to them.)

In particular, it has the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method from `Object`.  That gives a code indicating the type — here `[` for an array, `L` indicating that each element is a reference, `Runningpath` giving the type of reference, `;` and `@` separators, and a hex representation of the array's hash code, which may be its address in memory or some other unique number.

So if you want some other way of displaying an array, you'll have to do it ‘manually’.

Other problems with arrays on the JVM result from them having run-time typing — they were part of Java long before generics were added, and interoperate badly with generics (e.g. you can't create an array of a generic type) — and being both mutable and covariant (and hence not type-safe in some cases).

[List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/)s, like other [Collection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/)s and data structures, are proper objects: they have methods such as `toString()`, which you can override; they can have generic type parameters; they're type-safe; they can have many implementations, including subclasses; and they're much better supported by the standard library and by many third-party libraries too.

So unless you have a particular need (vararg processing, Java interoperability, or a dire need to save every possible byte of memory), life will go easier if you use lists instead of arrays!

Comment: a detailed answer indeed. may i ask, if i use listOf instead, all inputs are in the same row, is it possible to make each input in seperate rows? Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Two basic approaches: you could call `println()` on each element separately, either with a traditional `for` loop, as in your Option 2, or with `forEach()` e.g. `path.forEach{ println(it) }`; or you could join them to a single string with line separators and print that, e.g. `println(path.joinToString(System.lineSeparator()))`.  The latter may take a little more memory but may be slightly quicker.  (`\n` works on some platforms, but `System.lineSeparator()` is safer and will work everywhere.)

Comment: "_The problem is that on the JVM, an array is not an object_" – the opposite is true, an array **is** an `Object`, even arrays of primitive types. For example, if you were to do `int[] i = {}; b = i instanceof Object;` you'd get `b == true` as a result (same with `i = IntArray(0); b = i is Any`, at least on the JVM). So an array has all the methods of `Object` / `Any`, it simply just does not override any of them.

Comment: @Slaw I sit corrected!  (As you say, they're strange sorts of objects, though, with different semantics re. type parameterisation and subtyping, different operators, &c.)  Kotlin hides the difference pretty well (even better than does with the differences between primitives and objects, between fields and accessors, and between static and instance members), but like all abstractions it ‘[leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction)’ occasionally.

Comment: (I've updated this answer, to fix the characterisation of Java arrays.  Thanks to @Slaw for pointing that out.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) for that:

```kotlin
println(path.joinToString("\n"))
```

The joinToString() is actually available for both the List and the Array, but I'd recommend using the List as you'd have immutability and many other extensions on that, that will help your on manipulating the datas.